# How can I bind between types in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, relational-database

I have a simple setup in which my Angular app retrieves an array of Items and People (owners) from an API, and posts the objects when changes are made.

[image]

Is there a simple and direct way I can two-way bind a dropdown for `person` objects (using `person.id`) to the `item.ownerId` field?

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uiLZmaWZl9zd7o5T602d?p=preview) with my code.

---

I've tried building my own directives to accomplish this, but I can't seem to get it working.

- Could `$formatters` and `$parsers` be a solution?
- Would wrapping the field in another directive with an isolated be a good approach?
- I've tried using `$scope.$watch` statements, but it ends up bouncing updates back and forth until the browser runs out of memory
- `ng-change` is the solution I am currently using, but it is really too specific.  I need two-way binding, and I need a solution that works for arbitrary binding between different types (where I can define an injective relationship)

Answer (score 1):

You're close.  I think you're having trouble because the value of each option in the select element is a `person` object, but you don't have a `person` object in your `Items`, you only have the person's Id (the `ownerId`).

Bind the value of the select element options to be `person.id`, and set ng-model to `item.ownerId` and you should be good.

```
<select ng-options="person.id as person.name for person in people" ng-model="item.ownerId"></select>
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/U2EBjhZbtIPX9UdhOTnq?p=preview).  Press the button to programmatically re-assign the flowerpot to Oscar, and watch the view update.

Comment: Wow! I did not know you could do that. Thanks! Do you know how I could emulate the `as` functionality in a different setting? This works for `select` tags, but I have other UI controls that strictly bind to objects. I'm reading through the [`select.js`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/083f496d46415c01fec6dfa012da63235d0996e4/src/ng/directive/select.js) code now.

Comment: What other controls are you thinking of?

Comment: I'm also using the [ngQuickDate](https://github.com/adamalbrecht/ngQuickDate) directive, which binds to a Date object.  The Items API transmits and receives dates in a specific string format, so I need to bind the date object to a string via functions that convert back and forth. It's not quite as simple as accessing a property of the object, but it's a similar scenario.

Comment: So you want to display the date in a different format than it is saved as?  Can you make a plunker?  You should probably post it as a separate question.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll make a separate question. I was able to bind the datepicker to my particular API-formatted date string by modifying the `$formatters` and `$parsers` in the _original_ directive code, but I want to find a way to arbitrarily wrap a field in a directive that binds by function conversion, rather than copying the value.  Thanks for your input.